# Why do some of my directories need to be writeable that shouldn't be?

Tags: permissions

Otherwise, the site turns blank. 
wp-content needs web user writable, wp-admin/includes also. i don't like it, from what I understand, I should be able to have all of this as read-only for the web user. It can read it... why won't it show it?

Is it possible for a plugin or theme to cause this?

Comment: You may want to review this article about good WordPress permissions, safe but updatable: https://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress#Core_Directories_.2F_Files

Comment: Hi, thanks but I have been studying that article! In fact, I managed to set MOST perms to 750 or 640 now. But those listed above... still require Write access from web user, no matter what, just to display the site. That's the part I don't get.. why need Write, to Read? xD